# Iterate over dataframe with NaN condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, nan

I have a table where I want to extract data from table A and collate it as table B:

Table A:

| Day | City A | City B | City C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mon | NaN | Mike | NaN |
| Tue | NaN | NaN | Joe |
| Wed | Jack | Charlie | NaN |

Table B:

| Day | Name | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mon | Mike | City B |
| Tue | Joe | City C |
| Wed | Jack | City A |
| Wed | Charlie | City B |

I have pulled this information from an excel sheet and am using python to undertake this task.
My thinking is I need to draw the data in as a dataframe, iterate over the rows looking for entries that do not contain NaN and store their location and associated data in a new dataframe.

Unfortunately, i'm getting stuck on placing conditions to ignore the NaN entries, I am trying to test this out step-by-step and have got this far:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_excel('./csvtasks/rosta.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet2')
    
    #open new excel to write to with new variable df2
    #determine whether null or not
    dg=df.notnull()
    #loop over rows
    for i,j in dg.iteritems():
        if dg.bool==FALSE:
            print('skipped something') #i want this to skip but using this print to see if it's actually skipped anything
        else:
            print (i,j)
            #this will be replace by some command that uses the df.iloc[something] and writes to df2, printing for now so i can see what it does
    #loop to end
    #close file
```

All this does is give me the whole dataframe as a bool like this:

| Day | City A | City B | City C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | False | True | False |
| True | False | False | True |
| True | True | True | False |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `stack`

```
s = df.set_index('Day').stack().reset_index()
s.columns = ['Day','City','Name']
s
Out[43]: 
   Day    City     Name
0  Mon  City B     Mike
1  Tue  City C      Joe
2  Wed  City A     Jack
3  Wed  City B  Charlie
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `melt` then `dropna`

```py
out = (df.melt(id_vars='Day', var_name='Name', value_name='City')
       .dropna())
```

```
print(out)

   Day    Name     City
2  Wed  City A     Jack
3  Mon  City B     Mike
5  Wed  City B  Charlie
7  Tue  City C      Joe
```